# Rails: create from two pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm very new to Rails, so maybe I'm just missing the "Rails way" of doing this, but I have a model, call it `Post`. I can create a post from the canonical `posts/new` page but also from another page, say `home/index`.

In `home/index` i have a `form_for @post` (slightly different from the one in `posts/new`, but say that i can use a partial). The problem is that in the `PostController.create` I cannot pass the newly created @post object back to `home/index` (in case of errors) because:

- if I don't specify a page to render, it will automatically render `posts/new`
- i don't know the calling page in order to redirect it to the right calling page (`posts/new` or `home/index`)
- even if i knew it (hacking the request referrer or using `redirect_to :back`), redirect_to doesn't pass objects back, so that @post is empty when called from `home/index`

Any help? thanks

**EDIT**

Maybe a possible solution would be to get the calling controller / action from the request and render it back. Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you could achieve what you're trying to do by checking the referer:

```
def create
  @post = Post.new

  if @post.update_attributes(params[:post])
    # redirect as appropriate
  else
    render :action => case request.referer
      when new_post_path then "posts/new"
      when "/" then "home/index" # assuming that home/index is the root of the site
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the referrer page, you can make a hidden field with the name `redirect`. You can use it in the controller.

```
redirect_to params[:redirect] || posts_path
```

Have you tried that you pass the post's id in the query string to the `home/index`

eg: `/home/index?post_id=42`

Answer (score 0):

You can find out who called your page by looking at

```
request.referrer
```

I don't know if this is the "rails way" but here's my solution.

You can add a route for

```
match home/index/(:id) => "home#index"
```

and redirect to this after creating the `Post`. Then in your `Home` controllers `index` action just do a

```
@Post = Post.find(params[:index]) if params[:index]
```

Your view should display the post if `@Post` exists

I like this approach because it keeps all the logic where it should be. Routing logic in the controller and view logic in the views.